# Add File Type column to metadata navigation

Tags: column, metadata-navigation, asset-library

I have an Asset Library in my SharePoint site and in the default All Content view there is a File Type column. I want to make this column available in my Metadata Navigation, but for some reason this column is not available in any other view, it's not listed under the columns in the Library, and I can't add it in from the existing site columns.

How can I add this column into other views or into metadata navigation so users can sort media by file type? I don't want to have to create a column where users manually select a file type.